# Konica Minolta Bizhub C250i paper size error

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer

I am constantly getting an error in printer Konica Minolta Bizhub C250i that states that there is insufficient amount of paper of chosen size (even if there is plenty). I then have to choose from buttons that are A4, A3, Custom size.

This message appears despite correct settings in PC. I always choose the paper size I need and then tray that I want to be used. And the message is still there.

I've tried changing printer settings within PC and also within printer itself but nothing helped.

Rough translation is →

> No paper of correct format. Insert paper to the manual tray or choose the
> tray.

Is there any possible solution?

[image: The error]

Comment: Is the Media Type set the same? I see on your image that is Hruby 1 (thick?).

Comment: There might be a hardware problem on the printer with the mechanism that measures the paper height in the feeder.

Comment: @ServiceDeskBunny Yes, that means thick. And Yes the media type is also always set the same.

Comment: @harrymc thanks I'll have that checked